# ubr uploader , windows : ERROR: Failed to find flength file

Tags: php, wamp, file-upload

I've setup [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/) on my Windows machine and can run Perl scripts on WAMP. I am setting up [Uber-Uploader](http://uber-uploader.sf.net/) and now it just telling me `ERROR: Failed to find flength file`.

I've set all the paths in `uber.ini` and in the Perl script. I guess there's something missing out there. :(

Comment: You need to add some links to what you're actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you're getting are in the PHP scripts.

The name for the file that's missing is set like this:

```
$flength_file = $TEMP_DIR . $UPLOAD_ID . '.dir/' . $UPLOAD_ID . '.flength';
```

Try looking into that and please also edit your tags to include php instad of perl.

Comment: what do you mean with edit tags wo include php instead of perl ?

Comment: The tags on your question here. You added the perl tag, but this is a problem with php code, so you'd get more help by adding a php tag.

Comment: I edited it , not working :( it's not even creating the .flength file ! permissions on windows folders maybe ? imagine windows with chmod , the life would have been easier then ...